# に行く grammar with 行く replaced by other verbs

Tags: grammar, verbs-of-motion

I wonder if I can be more creative and replace 行くwith other verbs.

> トニーくんは皆さんのためにコーヒー準備しに部屋を出ました。(1)
>
> トニーくんは部屋を出て皆さんのためにコーヒー準備しました。(2)

- Tony left the room to prepare coffee for everyone. (1)
- Tony left the room and prepared coffee for everyone. (2)

The first sentence sounds more natural if 行くcan be replaced with 出る, since both Japanese verbs express direction. I want to know if I am doing it the acceptable way. Thank you.

EDIT: I meant, the meaning will change depending on the last verb used.

- に行く: Go to do something
- に出る: Leave (a place) to do something

A demonstrating example with 行く even though it is irrelevant :

> 昨日 トニーくんは勉強しに図書館に行きました。(3)

- Yesterday Tony went to the library to study.

Comment: `コーヒー準備しに / コーヒー準備しました` -- should be コーヒー**を**準備しに/コーヒー**を**準備しました or コーヒー**の**準備**を**しに/コーヒー**の**準備**を**しました

Comment: @Chocolate - I thought that I could omit を when I use the "suru" verb, but I had better be more detailed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the functions of the に particle is showing the purpose/goal of an action ([動作・作用の目的を表す)](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AB-590835#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88), ie "買いに行く", so you can replace 行く, but as Chocolate helpfully corrected me in the comments, the way you express this in Japanese changes depending on whether or not the verb expresses movement.

If it is a movement verb, such as 行く/来る/帰る, you use the 連用形{れんようけい} form/masu stem of the action or a noun that expresses an action + に + the movement verb.

Examples:

> 友達が遊びに来るんだ。
>   買いに行く。
>   映画を見に行く。
>   買い物に行きます。

If you are using any other verb except for that, you need to add の before に.

Examples:

> ご飯を食べるのに使うお茶碗 
>   えんぴつは字を書くのに使います。

Comment: `You can absolutely substitute 行く with other verbs` --「 **連用形＋に** ＋行く/来る/帰るetc.(移動を表す動詞)」はいいですけど、「 **連用形+に** +使う(移動を表さない動詞)」（eg 字を書きに使う）は無理ですよね・・「 **連体形+の+に** ＋使う」になるわけですし。。

Comment: @Chocolate そのことについてネット上で何も見つけなかったんだけどChocolateさんの言う通りのようです。 
グーグルで"食べに使う"とかの件数を探索と一切ありませんから。
答えを修正したので間違いを指定て訂正くれてありがとうございます。(*^-^*)